# Определение мобильного браузера

Tags: php

У кого есть готовое решение? И кто что может сказать по этому поводу?

Comment: На хэшкоде были примеры и ссылки на примеры скриптов. Тут уже не гуглите а хэшкодьте))) если найду апну.

Comment: хешкодил - не помогло, жду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эта тема! Советую обратить внимание конкретно на ссылки! А конкретно в топике ТС'а.

Answer (score -2):

Самое простое написать на javascript, и времени немного займет и если это ваш сайт - по килобайтам немного будет (сам скрипт отдельно и ссылка на него).

```
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(navigator.userAgent);</script>
```

Не обязательно быть кодером - главное знать, где искать!

Comment: а скрипт где?

Comment: И верно будет `<script type="text/javascript" src="mobile.js"></script>` знаток ипиомать...

Comment: для мобильных UA поидет и просто javascript *ипомать*

Comment: @DimmoS с такой логикой и подходом далеко не зайдешь! Это нужно понимать и чем раньше тем лучше!

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] тожа полезная функция но не во всех браузерах работает

Comment: Мне вот интересно, зачем было копировать сюда скрипт из темы на которую я дал ссылку в комментарии к вопросу? у меня слов нет)))

Comment: доволен???